# Displaying multiple images in Tkinter with scrollbar

Tags: python, tkinter, python-2.x

I want to design a widget that displays multiple images of fixed size (300x300) stacked in a column. To do this, I created a text widget of size 300x800 and then added image labels inside it. I'm adding 4 images in the example below. Since the total vertical size of the stacked images are more, it's expanding the size of the text widget and it doesn't even fit the screen. I want all the images to stay inside the text widget without expanding it and add a scrollbar to the text widget so that I can scroll and see all the images. In the code below, I am able to add scrollbar but it doesn't work.

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
from PIL import *
from PIL import Image
import os
root = Tk();

text = Text(root, width = 300, height=300)
text.grid(row=0, column=0)
text.grid_propagate(False)


class ImageLabel:
    def __init__(self, master, img_file):        
        label = Label(master)
        label.img = PhotoImage(file=img_file)
        label.config(image=label.img)
        label.pack(side="bottom")

## Adding images to text widget
width = 300
src = "./"
my_item_id = 770353540339
count = 0;
file_name = str(my_item_id)+'_'+str(count)+'.jpeg';
full_file_name = os.path.join(src, file_name)

imagelabels = []
while os.path.isfile(full_file_name):
    im = Image.open(full_file_name)
    height = width*im.size[1]/im.size[0]
    im.thumbnail((width, height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    im.save(str(count),'gif')
    imagelabels.append(ImageLabel(text, str(count)))
    count = count+1;
    file_name = str(my_item_id)+'_'+str(count)+'.jpeg';
    full_file_name = os.path.join(src, file_name)
    print(count)

## Adding scrollbar
scrollbar = Scrollbar(root, orient=VERTICAL, command=text.yview)
scrollbar.grid(row=0,column=1, sticky='ns')
text.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a text widget to contain images, you must use the `image_create` or `window_create` method rather than using `pack` to place the image in the widget. You'll also need to insert a newline after each image to get them to stack vertically.